# Open source geometry service like ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, open-source-gis

Does anyone know of an open source GIS server that provide similar functionality to ArcGIS' web services server? For example, the service would provide a similar geometry service that buffers feature shapes and returns the buffered shape? Or does joins or reprojections of geometry?

Comment: I would have a look at GeoServer with Web Processing Service. See a slide show http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/processing-data-in-geoserver-with-wps-and-sql-views.

Comment: Also if the Web Processing Services that come with Geoserver aren't enough, you can always create your own using GeoScript and publish them to GeoServer. You can write the scripts in Javascript...Javascript_Guru ;)

Comment: Sounds like just PostGIS will do what you're wanting already.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possible examples.

[**JSTS Topology Suite**](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)

The JSTS Topology Suite is a JavaScript library of spatial predicates and functions for processing geometry conforming to the Simple Features Specification for SQL published by the Open Geospatial Consortium. JSTS Topology Suite is also a JavaScript port of the well established Java library JTS Topology Suite with a built in parser for OpenLayers geometries.

[**Njord.js**](https://github.com/atlefren/njord.js)

There is an abundance of open source geoprocessing libs for various programming languages... with the surge in JavaScript popularity and complicated Single Page Apps (both generally and in the GIS domain) there is a need to aviod round-tripping to the server for doing geoprocessing tasks such as intersections, buffering etc.

The main goal should be to replicate the functionality of JTS, but done so in a modern, lightweight and easy-to use way that is compatible with sensible JavaScript practices.